# how to use cordova camera plugin with framework7 react

Tags: reactjs, cordova, initialization, cordova-plugins, html-framework-7

I’ve been trying for a long time to integrate Cordova’s camera plugin with the React library but whether it’s in the app.js, app.jsx, or cordova-app.js file, nothing even works the line

```
    document.addEventListener(“deviceready”, onDeviceReady, false);
   function onDeviceReady() {
console.log(navigator.camera);
}
```

So if you could tell me how to implement the cordova plugins, I would be delighted because in the official doc or even on different website, nothing explains to me how to implement them in the react or vue framework7.

Only for Framework7 Core but for React, Vue or Svelte nothing.

Please answer me as soon as possible.

And little suggestions for experienced contributors, you should add the installation and initialization of cordova plugin for the React, Vue and Svelte libraries in the official doc ??

Thank you.

Comment: I have created numerous F7-Vue cordova apps and never experience problems with cordova plugins. Use it like always, make sure you have included cordova.js in your index.html and call cordova APIs after deviceready event

Answer (score 0):

Add cordova into the Index.html

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Install your plugin using cordova plugin add 'Desired Plugin Name'

Add device ready event listener

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
  alert('Device ready event fired!');
   alert(cordova.plugins); // Undefined
});
```

Then refer plugin inside your device ready (or after device ready fires)

```
  window.cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
        function (result) {
            console.log('Result: ', result)
            alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
        },
        function (error) {
            alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
        }
      );
```